# Pass pointer to function and change it after function returns

Tags: c++, pointers

This might be trivial but I am having a hard time making it work. It's for a game engine, but the rules apply for C++, I guess.

I have an object, let's call it `Car`, and then I have a `Bike`.

From a function in `Car`, I am passing a pointer to a function in `Bike`:

```cpp
void Car::MyFunction(){
    int32* MyPointer = nullptr;

    Bike* bike = createBike();
    bike.Init(MyPointer);   // i pass a nullptr initially to my bike object
    
    int32 value = 5;
    MyPointer = &value;   //here I change the content of that pointer
}
```

Here is my `Init` function on my bike:

```cpp
void Bike::Init(int32* &thePointer)   //passing the pointer as reference and not by value
{
     InstancePointer = thePointer;
}
```

Later in the future, some event fires on the bike object and I check the contents of `InstancePointer`:

```cpp
if (InstancePointer) {
    log("It's a valid pointer");
} else {
    log("It's a null pointer");   // i am seeing this message here
}
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong, or maybe this is not even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but here `MyPointer = &value;` you make `MyPointer` point at `value` and `value` is then destroyed, so the pointer is left "dangling". Dereferencing the pointer after the function has returned would make the program have undefined behavior. That's however not what's happening since `MyPointer` is also local to that function. What _are_ you trying to do with the pointer?

Comment: Yes you are right, value is destroyed and then pointer to it becomes invalid, now I understand! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the behavior you are expecting is to give Bike ownership of an object that you can edit from different places. In this case, given the ownership semantics, I recommend using `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`. If the bike owns this object alone, then you should use a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`.
As for your question, this provided code achieves the following:

1. Allows `Car` to initialize the bike with a `Foo` through the `Init` function
2. Provides a method inside `Bike` that tests the validity of its `InstancePointer`
3. Shares the ownership of the `Foo` object between `Car` and `Bike`, allowing both to edit the same address in memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
        int value_;
        Foo(int value) : value_{value} {}
};

struct Bike {
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> InstancePointer;
        void Init(const std::shared_ptr<Foo> &thePointer)
        {
                InstancePointer = thePointer;
        }

        void Test()
        {
                if (InstancePointer)
                        std::cout << "It's a valid pointer and its value is " << InstancePointer->value_ << std::endl;
                else
                        std::cout << "It's a null pointer\n";
        }
        };

struct Car {
        Bike *bike;
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> car_foo;
        void MyFunction()
        {
                bike = new Bike();
                car_foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(1234);
                bike->Init(car_foo);
        }

        void ChangeBike()
        {
                car_foo->value_ = 4321;
        }

};


int main() {
        Car car;
        car.MyFunction();
        car.bike->Test();
        car.ChangeBike();
        car.bike->Test();
}
```

The program outputs:

```
It's a valid pointer and its value is 1234
It's a valid pointer and its value is 4321
```